# get connected to flash media server via RTMP android

Tags: android, flash, media, rtmp

I want to make connection to FMS (flash media server) in my android application.

Please suggest if there is any way to get connected to FMS via RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [`NetConnection`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html) class? It establishes an RTMP connection to a RTMP-capable server.

Establishing a connection is easy:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

// Listen for the netstatus event
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);

// Connect to your server
nc.connect("IP_GOES_HERE");

function onStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    if (e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
    {
        // Connection has been established
    }
}
```

Looks like you don't want to do it in Flash but in Java. There is one library I know off that implements RTMP on the client side which is [Flazr](http://flazr.com/).

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the answer..... I tried it not worked.... It would be helpful if you can explain in detail.... i.e. how to use  
NetConnection with android native application......

Comment: @param: Are you getting any security or I/O errors? It might have something to do with the policy file.

Comment: @kevin: well when I add NetConnection() it gives error..... (NetConnection cannot be resolved to a type..)......what package or library do I need to add...  Please suggest....

Comment: @param: You will need to import `flash.net.NetConnection` and `flash.events.NetStatusEvent`. Check the link I gave you to the documentation, and example is right there: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: @kevin: yes you are right I need to import them but that are in case of flash app.... but In the case of android native application we do not have these packages available..... that's why it gives error....

Comment: @kevin: no.... I am not using Adobe Air for android app. It would be easier in case of Adobe Air, I guess..   I am working on native android application (java).... That's why I am having issues with netConnection()...........  :(

Comment: @param: Ahhhh, that clears it up. You should remove the flash tag in that case, you could have a look at the following library which implements RTMP in java: http://flazr.com/